# What kind of SCTP support is there on various Windows versions?

Tags: windows, network-programming, network-protocols, sctp

What kind of [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) support is there on various Windows versions?

Comment: Does [Windows.next](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) support SCTP?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Out of the box, there are none, on any versions of Windows.(Microsoft has claimed there is no customer demand, so I always encourage anyone looking for SCTP on windows contact Microsoft and express their need for one..)

There are 3rd party implementations, e.g.

[sctplib](http://www.sctp.de/sctp-download.html)

Comment: +1 for "express their need for none" well the microsoft guys wont be using the internet that often or maybe stackoverflow specifically. "P

Comment: You might want to watch out for SctpDrv - I kept getting BSoDs on Win7, SP1.

Comment: Is there any SCTP 3rd party implementations for windows8?.
So far, as I know SctpDrv does not.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/778329/sctp-driver.html

Answer (score 5):

Recently, Windows support has been added to this userspace SCTP stack:
http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/sctp-user-land-stack.html

It will have a paper in 2012 ICCCN describing its implementation.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol):

> The following operating systems implement SCTP:
>
> - AIX Version 5
> - Generic BSD with external patch at KAME project
> - Cisco IOS 12
> - DragonFly BSD since version 1.4
> - FreeBSD, version 7 and above
> - HP-UX, 11i v2 and above
> - Operating systems using Linux kernel 2.4 and newer
> - QNX Neutrino Realtime OS, 6.3.0 and above
> - Sun Solaris 10 and above
>
> Various third-party implementations of SCTP exist for other operating systems. FreeBSD contains the SCTP reference implementation.
>
> Userspace library:
>
> - The SCTP library (sctplib), with a [Windows XP port](http://www.sctp.be/sctplib/index.htm).

So apparently there is no native support in Windows at all. Only through 3rd-party software or libraries.

Comment: What other libraries are available and is there anything available for Vista and Win7?

Comment: Since sctplib is a userspace library it should work without problems on Vista or Windows 7 too. Apart from that, did you try Google already? I hear they return all kinds of fancy results when searching for "windows sctp library".

Comment: 3rd party kernel extension and userspace library for Mac OS X: https://github.com/sctplab/SCTP_NKE_ElCapitan