# SOCK_SEQPACKET availability?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip

When using a raw TCP socket, there is a need for doing message framing, as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37496/TCP-IP-Protocol-Design-Message-Framing), either with a length prefix, or with delimiters.

I came accross the "SOCK_SEQPACKET" socket option today, which could apparently do the message framing almost transparently.

What is the availability of "SOCK_SEQPACKET" amongst platforms and OSes at the moment? (Windows, OSX, Linux, IOS, Android...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I you uses `SOCK_SEQPACKET` of `AF_INET`, this way:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
```

You won't get a TCP socket. The socket will be a SCTP socket, if your platform supports it.

SCTP is not yet widely used. Latest Linux versions supports it (if SCTP is enabled).

There are [some libraries also for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153700/what-kind-of-sctp-support-is-there-on-various-windows-versions).

Answer (score 1):

SCTP is still not available on Mac OS X (El Captain).
There is a 3rd party open-source kernel extension at https://github.com/sctplab/SCTP_NKE_ElCapitan - But it is unsigned, therefore you have to disable Apple System Integrity Protection.

See e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114217/sctp-kernel-extension-for-mavericks

*Equally, you cannot use SOCK_SEQPACKET with AF_UNIX on Mac OS X too.*

Answer (score 0):

**Linux**: available [since version 2.6.4](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)

**Mac OS**: [not available](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html) *(better source?)*

**Windows**: [not available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/19/af_unix-comes-to-windows/)